# Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: insert_records() passed non-traversable object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, moodle

i want to insert my form data to **moodle** db,

i have 2 table which needs to update every time im trying to insert at the same time,

here is my code

```
$result = $DB->update_record('newmodule', $newmodule);

if (!$DB->get_record('newmodule1', array('course_id' => $newmodule->id))) {
  //now i need to insert data to db
//object builder 
    foreach ($newmodule as $key => $value) {

        if($key == 'time' || $key == 'audio' || $key == 'entxt' || $key == 'fatxt' || $key == 'url'){
            $new->$key = $value;
        }elseif ($key == 'id') {
            $new->course_id = $value;
        }

    }
//just trying for finding a way 

        $result = $DB->insert_records('newmodule1', $new);


    }
```

every time trying to insert data i getting this

> Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer:
>   insert_records() passed non-traversable object

how can i split stdclass, then insert each part to db ?

Comment: So what is the problem, be a little more specific

Comment: And where/what is this `stdClass` you want to split

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry dude i tought title will explain it all ! my problem is with non-traversable object !

Comment: in which line you got this error,and really this error is occurring? try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1)` on top of your page just after `<?php` and check what  and how many errors are actually occurring in your script

Comment: $result = $DB->insert_records('newmodule1', $new); this line

Comment: dude its moodle problem, its not php,

Answer (score 1):

ok i found working solution,

```
        for ($i=0; $i <=count($newmodule->time); $i++) { 
            $new->course_id = $newmodule->id;
            $new->videourl  = $newmodule->url;
            $new->audio     = $newmodule->audio[$i];
            $new->time      = $newmodule->time[$i];
            $new->entxt     = $newmodule->entxt[$i];
            $new->fatxt     = $newmodule->fatxt[$i];
            $DB->insert_record('newmodule1', $new);

            unset($new);
        }
```

all i did was to read array object then create new object then submit it to db then unset all created object, thats all

ps:lol i got negative for my question, because 1 person dont know anything about moodle !!! WOW !